# Cannot resolve symbol with @annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop

I've got this EnableArgumentLogging class

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EnableArgumentLogging {
}
```

I would like to use it in my other class, called LoggingAspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

    @Before("@annotation(EnableArgumentLogging)")
    public void logArguments(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        StringBuilder argumentString = new StringBuilder();
        Arrays.stream(joinPoint.getArgs()).forEach(o -> argumentString.append(o.toString()));
        LOGGER.info("Method name : [" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "], parameter(s): [" + argumentString + "]");
    }
}
```

In this case I got an error: `Cannot resolve symbol 'EnableArgumentLogging'`

What did I miss to add here?

Comment: If EnableArgumentLogging annotation is in another package, then add the path to package like @Before("@annotation(my.annotations.EnableArgumentLogging)")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@annotation()` accepts fully qualified name of the annotation, that is class name with package.

Example:
`@Before("@annotation(com.example.annotations.EnableArgumentLogging)")`